# What is the difference between using the constant() function and referencing a constant directly by name?

Tags: php, constants

AS per PHP manual `constant()` is useful if you need to retrieve the value of a constant, but do not know its name. I.e. it is stored in a variable or returned by a function.

```
define("MAXSIZE", 100);

echo MAXSIZE;
echo constant("MAXSIZE"); // same thing as the previous line
```

If some one does not know `MAXSIZE` , how can he use **`constant("MAXSIZE")`**. Is that enough to use **`echo MAXSIZE`** ?. Can someone please explain with an example? I tried the  below code and it doesn't work.

```
    define("MAXSIZE", 100);

    $x = MAXSIZE;
    echo constant($x);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this it, should work

```
define("MAXSIZE", 100);

$x = "MAXSIZE";
echo constant($x);
```

The method `constant()` will return the value of a defined constant if you have string variable of it.

Consider this example.

```
define("MAX", 1000);
define("MIN", 1);

$val = 50; 
$const = null;
if ( $val < 50 ) {
    $const = "MAX";
} else {
    $const = "MIN";
}

echo constant($const); // output 1
```

Comment: @zzlalani Thanks a lot. In fact, PHP manual should give an example for it.

Answer (score 2):

By [*do not know its name*](https://www.php.net/constant) the manual means `constant()` can accept an expression (e.g a variable or a concatenation of a string and a variable) as the constant's name in addition to a string literal.

This description is indeed a bit misleading. A better way to describe this would be to say *you don't have to know its name*. For example, if you have the constant's name stored in a variable or defined by a class, you cannot reference the constant directly by name. This is where `constant()` comes in handy, allowing us to dynamically reference the constant's name without actually *knowing* it.

For example, consider the difference between:

```
define('MAXSIZE', 100);
echo MAXSIZE;
```

and

```
define('MAXSIZE-2', 100);

$sizeConstantPrefix = 'MAXSIZE';
$sizeConstantSuffix = '-2';

echo constant($sizeConstantPrefix.$sizeConstantSuffix);
```

or the more extreme

```
class whatever {
   const 'MAXSIZE-2' = 100;
}

$className          = 'whatever'
$sizeConstantPrefix = 'MAXSIZE';
$sizeConstantSuffix = '-2';

echo constant($className.'::'.$sizeConstantPrefix.$sizeConstantSuffix);
```